# (React-table) Bold font for only the first row with a set condition that is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, react-table

I am working with react-table, and I wanted to bold only the first row which has the word('test') in it (next rows which have the word 'test' won't be bolded, after the first one is bolded)

```
 const makeCellBold = (value: {} | null | undefined, original: any) => {
   return <Typography fontWeight={original.DummyTestString.includes('test') ? '500' 
: 'inherit'}>{value}</Typography>;
 };



 return [
    {
      Header: 'header1',
      accessor: 'accessor1',
      Cell: ({ value, row }) => makeCellBold(value, row.original),
    },
    {
      id: 'row',
      Header: 'header2',
      accessor: 'accessor2',
      Cell: ({ value, row }) => makeCellBold(value, row.original),
    },

 {
      id: 'row',
      Header: 'header3',
      accessor: 'accessor3',
      Cell: ({ value, row }) => makeCellBold(value, row.original),
    },

]
```

I tried to add a counter or a boolean value which get triggered after the first bolded row, but it did not work (either none of the rows get bolded, or all rows with 'test' in them get bolded, and that's not what I want

Comment: Can you please paste the full working code that you have tried